# FirebaseListAdapter<> Not Working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397) tutorial to create a chat app. This is my `displayChatMessages()` method:

```java
ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessages>(this, ChatMessages.class, R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessages model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageBody());
            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But I get a red underline at this part:

```java
(this, ChatMessages.class, R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference())
```

Android Studio says

> `Firebaselistadapter()` in Firebaselistadapter cannot be applied to...

**UPDATE:** This is the error message:

> Error:(76, 19) error: constructor FirebaseListAdapter in class FirebaseListAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: FirebaseListOptions
>   found: MainActivity,Class,int,DatabaseReference
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends Object declared in class FirebaseListAdapter

Comment: Do you mind pasting the entire error message there? I suspect it complains about matching argument lists - check your last argument `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()` - don't you have a URL to your Firebase instance? You could pass in `new Firebase("https://<yourURL>..");`

Comment: are you using this `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'`? or an older one in dependencies?

Comment: I am using: compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.0.0'

Comment: The error message is now there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for complete error message - this helps greatly.
Based on that, I think this is what you need to do.

```
//Suppose you want to retrieve "chats" in your Firebase DB:
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats");
//The error said the constructor expected FirebaseListOptions - here you create them:
FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                    .setQuery(query, ChatMessages.class)
                     .setLayout(android.R.layout.message)
                    .build();
    //Finally you pass them to the constructor here:                
 adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessages>(options){
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessages model, int position) {
        // Get references to the views of message.xml
        TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

        // Set their text
        messageText.setText(model.getMessageBody());
        // Format the date before showing it
        messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", model.getMessageTime()));
    }
 };
```

Here is an [article](https://reformatcode.com/code/android/firabase-list-adapter-constructor-error) where the same issue was encountered.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I don't have any errors, but the listview doesn't show anything!

Comment: By the way, did you include the line `listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);`? Also check that your `query` points to a collection that exist on your Firebase DB.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need `FirebaseListOptions`, please use this:

```
Query query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().orderByChild("name").equalTo(name);
FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessages> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessages>()
    .setQuery(query, ChatMessages.class)
    .build();

FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessages> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessages>(options) {
@Override
protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessages model, int position) {
    //code here

 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but "query" is unresolved. What is it? Can you please explain more?

Comment: its the query that you do inside the FirebaseListAdapter, its this `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()` that you had added in your listadapter. Check the edit, do a query like the above