# How do i put a database reference into firebaselistadapter? i am getting an error when i put ref as in the code below

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, listadapter, firebaseui

I need to add a database reference to the list adapter how do i do that from this code

```
private void populateTheData()
{
    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstView);
    DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    adapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this,ChatMessage.class,R.layout.list_of_message,ref.getDatabase()){
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            TextView txtMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView txtUser=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView txtTime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.message_time);
            txtMessage.setText(model.getMessageText());
            txtUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
            txtTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-mm-yyyy(HH:mm:ss)",model.getMessageTime()));

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line of code:

```
adapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this,ChatMessage.class,R.layout.list_of_message,ref.getDatabase()){
```

with

```
adapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this,ChatMessage.class,R.layout.list_of_message,ref){
```

Your `ref` variable is a `DatabaseReference`. I'm sure `ref.getDatabase()` does not return a `DatabaseReference`.

Comment: Error:(87, 17) error: constructor FirebaseListAdapter in class FirebaseListAdapter<T> cannot be applied to given types;
required: FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage>
found: MainActivity,Class<ChatMessage>,int,DatabaseReference
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in class FirebaseListAdapter

Comment: It's not working because another reason. The initial problem is solved. I see in this error that you are using a `FirebaseListAdapter` and not a `FirebaseListOptions` as it is found in your code.

Comment: I have found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690974/firebaselistadapter-not-working?rq=1